# Design patterns for flask API implementation

Tags: python, rest, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-restplus

I am using flask with flask-restplus and sqlalchemy.

My rest API function looks like the following:

```
@ns.route('/user')
class UsersCollection(Resource):

    @jwt_optional
    @permissions.user_has('admin_view')
    @ns.marshal_list_with(user_details)
    def get(self):
        """
        Returns list of users.
        """

        users = User.query.all()

        return users
```

I am willing to add additional data to `users` collection which should be returned by the API. Some of this data may be stored in other DB tables, while other is stored in memory.

What I am usually doing is something like this:

```
@ns.route('/user')
class UsersCollection(Resource):

    @jwt_optional
    @permissions.user_has('admin_view')
    @ns.marshal_list_with(user_details)
    def get(self):
        """
        Returns list of users.
        """

        users = User.query.all()

        # Add additional data
        for user in users:
          user.activity = UserActivity.query ...  # from DB 
          user.online_status = "Active" # Taken somewhere from memory

        return users
```

Obviously I don't like this approach of adding data to the User object on the fly. But what is the best design pattern to achieve it?

Comment: Well the only thing that comes to my mind would be having additional class that would contain user, his activities and his status.

Comment: I was actually reading about using marshmallow and defining another class, but don't have too much experience with it and I am not sure this is the right choice....

Comment: Sorry for late answer, was busy, I don't have much experience working in Python but if I had similar problem in kotlin or java I would definitely make another class. Python has ability to add functionality to instances which you are using right now, I'm not sure if that is considered best practice, for me its a bit odd, but if your project is small keep it this way, its simple and understandable, if you have to add more functionalities then make class which wraps all needed data together.

Comment: Another option would be inheritance but I prefer composition because it isn't tight coupled, you can easily add or remove things without changing your code much.

Answer (score 1):

About the design pattern, I recommend a DAO and Service approach, here's a good and short article about it:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/structuring-a-large-production-flask-application-7a0066a65447

About the models User/Activity relationship, I presume you have a mapped Activity model. If this is a One to One relationship, in the User model create a *activityId* field for the FK field and a *activity* relation where your ORM (I'll assume SQLAlchemy) will retrieve when *user.activity* is accessed.

```
class Activity(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    descrption = db.Column(db.String(255))

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    activity = db.relationship(Activity)
    activityId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Activity.id))
```

If you have a Many to Many relationship you'll have to create a third class called *ActivityUser* to map the relation

```
class ActivityUser(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    activity = db.relationship(Activity, lazy=True)
    user = db.relationship(User, lazy=True)
    activityId = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Activity))
    userId = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(User))
```

and you can retrieve the user activities like this (again assuming you use SQLAlchemy):

```
ActivityUser.query.filter(ActivityUser.userId == user.id).all()
```